# Junit report in Cucumber 7.15.0 version is not replacing the Example actual value

Tags: plugins, cucumber

Example value should be replaced in the report. But that's not happening.

```
 @Mailinator_POC
  Scenario Outline: Create Account - <LastName>
    Given application url "https://######" is launched
    When Enter "abc" in First Name field
    And Enter "<LastName>" in "Last name" field
    And Enter "abc" in Myf5 Email field
    And Enter "def" in myf5 Password field

    Examples: 
      | LastName |
      | X        |
```

Expected JUnit output

```
<testcase classname="Mailinator POC for MyF5 Account Creation" **name="Create Account - "X""** time="21.224">
```

Actual Junit report

```
<testcase classname="Mailinator POC for MyF5 Account Creation" **name="Create Account - <LastName> - Example #1.1"** time="21.224">
```